# Does this integral converge $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{x^4y^4+1}\ dxdy $?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to find out whether this integral is convergent or not.
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{x^4y^4+1}\ dxdy $$

I've tried to calculate it using the following variable changement, but it does'nt work i guess.$(x,y)=(r\cdot \cos(\theta),r\cdot \sin(\theta))$.

I also though of comparing the general term to another one that converge but i couldn't find.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3727813/532409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This answer is wrong, as the integral diverges.

Since I missed the case of $|x|>1$ and $|y|<1$ and vice versa.

---

Hint:

$$\int\frac1{x^4y^4+1}\ dx\ dy<\int\frac1{x^4y^4}\ dx\ dy$$

and use it to show convergence for when $|x|>1$ and $|y|>1$.

For $|\cdot|\le1$, show that it is finite.

Comment: Thank you very much @SimpleArt for solving my problem (y).

Comment: @hamzaboulahia :D no problem.

Comment: The integral diverges.  Look at the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, and $xy=1$.  In that region (of infinite area), we have $xy\le 1$ so that $\frac1{1+x^4y^4}\ge 1/2$.

Comment: I posted an answer that proves that the integral diverges.  The issue with the development here is that it misses the contributions from integrating in the regions $0<x<1$, $y>1$, etc.

Comment: I only saw this question now that Mark Viola's answer bumped it. My first reaction, too, was that this surely diverges because it is bounded away from zero in a set of infinite measure.

Comment: Dx Thanks @MarkViola

Comment: @simplybeautifulart2 You're welcome.  And I hope you're staying healthy and safe.

Answer (score 5):

> **The integral diverges.**

To see this, note that the integrand is positive.  Therefore, the value of the integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an upper bound of the value of the integral over any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $S$ be the set given by $S=\{(x,y)|xy\le 1, x>0, y>0\}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{1+x^4y^4}\,dx\,dy&\ge \iint_{S}\frac{1}{1+x^4y^4}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&\ge\frac12\iint_{S}\,dx\,dy
\end{align}$$

But the area of $S$ is clearly infinite.

> **Therefore, we conclude the integral of interest diverges.**

Comment: @hamzaboulahia  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  Note the answer you accepted was incorrect.

Comment: @Rodrigo The integrand is bounded below by $1/2$ on a domain that has infinite area.  That is how we conclude that the integral diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to show divergence: The substitution $x=u/|y|$ gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty{1\over x^4y^4+1}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty{1\over u^4+1}\cdot{du\over |y|} \right)dy=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty{du\over u^4+1}\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty{dy\over|y|}\right)$$

The improper integral over $u$ converges (to a nonzero value), but the one over $y$ diverges.

Remark: The use of $|y|$ instead of just $y$ in the substitution is to keep the limits of integeration running from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ for all $y$.  Technically the substitution is invalid for $y=0$, but that's only a single point in the integral over $y$.

My thanks to user Simply Beautiful Art for pointing out an error in the original version of the answer.

Comment: Hi Barry.  I hope that you're doing well and staying safe and healthy.

Comment: It's not immediately clear how you managed your first step. Should it not be $$I=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac1{u^4+y^{-4}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm du}{y^4}\right)~\mathrm dy?$$ Or perhaps I could see you might be substituting $u=xy$, but then that gives me $$I=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac1{u^4+1}\cdot\frac{\mathrm du}y\right)~\mathrm dy?$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, yes, you are quite right! I was thinking $x=u/y$ and somehow got $dx=du/y^4$ out of it. When I think more carefully now, it should actually be $dx=du/|y|$ to keep the $u$ limits running from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I'll fix it a little later, when I have more time. (I was just about out the door when I saw your comment.) Thanks for bringing the error(s) to my attention!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, fixed now. Again, thanks!

Comment: @MarkViola, thanks for the well wishes. I am indeed doing and staying as hoped, and hope the same is true for you.

Comment: Thank you Barry.  And (+1) for your post.