# Formal justification for the final part of an answer - double integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I am looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2097381/does-this-integral-converge-int-mathbbr2-frac1x4y41-dxdy/3727854?noredirect=1#comment9775432_3727854) and I can't find a way to formally justify the final conclusion.

I have to say I understand mostly everything involved in the proof. The only thing that's bugging me out is when the answerer concludes:

> Therefore, we conclude the integral of interest diverges.

I understand that the area of $S$ is infinite and, therefore, $ \frac{1}{2} \iint_S dx \, dy = +\infty.$ I also know that we have the inequality
$$ \frac{1}{2}\iint_S dx \, dy \leqslant \iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{1+x^4 \, y^4} \, dx \, dy $$
Obviously my intuition tells me that from this inequality the integral must assume the value $+\infty$ and therefore, it diverges. But I don't know how to prove such thing formally.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rigorous proof.

Since the region $S = \{(x,y):x>0, y>0, xy \leqslant1\}$ is unbounded, we have an improper double integral of $(x,y) \mapsto 1$ over $S$ which can be evaluated as

$$\int\int_S \,dx\,dy = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int\int_{S_n}\, dx\,dy$$

where $(S_n)$ is any sequence of compact rectifiable sets such that $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \subset \ldots$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty S_n = S$.

This is the precise definition of an improper  Riemann integral over a multidimensional domain (also called the extended Riemann integral) as discussed in treatments of advanced calculus such as *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres or *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak.  When the integrand is non-negative, the particular choice of the sets $S_n$ beyond the given requirements is arbitrary, and we can take for convenience

$$S_n = S \cap [1/n,n]^2$$

Hence,

$$\int\int_S \,dx\,dy = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int\int_{S_n}\, dx\,dy= \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{1/n}^n\left(\int_0^{1/x}\, dy\right)\,dx$$

Note that we express the double integral as the iterated integral on the RHS -- which is permissible for a non-negative integrand by Fubini's theorem.

Thus,

$$\int\int_S \,dx\,dy = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{1/n}^n\left(\int_0^{1/x}\, dy\right)\,dx = \lim_{n \to\infty}\int_{1/n}^n \frac{dx}{x}\\ = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\log n - \log \frac{1}{n}) = +\infty$$

Comment: The representation of the improper integral over $S$ as the limit of the iterated integral above should come to mind immediately for someone who has taken the typical third semester course on multidimensional calculus in a basic calculus sequence.